# Delete empty lines from a file

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I need to delete empty lines from a file (with spaces only - not null records).

The following command works only for null rows, but not in case of
spaces:

`sed '/^$/d' filename`

Can it be done using grep?

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/deleting-empty-lines-from-file.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `\s*` for blank lines containing only whitespace:

```bash
sed '/^\s*$/d' file
```

To save the changes back to the file use the `-i` option:

```bash
sed -i '/^\s*$/d' file
```

Edit:

The regex `^\s*$` matches a line that only contains whitespace, `grep -v` print lines that don't match a given pattern so the following will print all none black lines:

```bash
grep -v '^\s*$' file
```

Comment: If you know that the blank lines don't have whitespace, then you can reduce that grep to `grep . file`.

Comment: just for completeness: `awk 'NF' file`

Comment: `\s` is going to fail on many Unix machines (it's probably a  GNUism or perlism). Instead, the POSIX classes `[:blank:]` or `[:space:]` should be used.

Answer (score 4):

The POSIX portable way to do this is

```bash
sed -i '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d' file
```

or

```bash
grep -v '^[[:blank:]]*$' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```bash
sed -i '/^[ \t]*$/d' file-name
```

it will delete all blank lines having any no. of white spaces (spaces or tabs) i.e. (0 or more) in the file..

Note: there is a 'space' followed by '\t' inside the square bracket...

"`-i`" will force to write the updated contents back in the file... without this flag you can see the empty lines got deleted on the screen but the actual file will not be affected.

Answer (score 0):

It happened that the file was copied from Windows machine a the sed command (`sed '/^$/d' foo`) was not running correctly.

I ran following command and it worked.

```
$ dos2unix foo
```